# Android app in HTML

Tags: android, html, android-emulator, portability

I've looked at this doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

It seems it might be attractive strategy to use `HTML`/`Javascript` to get:

1. **result faster** (I can use my browser to create a prototype very quickly, just updating my page in the browser, and not waiting for emulator to be update my changes)
2. **avoid to to learn Android API too deep** (but use what I know HTML/CSS/JS instead)
3. **reuse my code, putting it to iOS, BlackBerry** (not only Android)

The only question I have.. Is whether someone already did it for real? Because tutorials that I've found - just show how to print `'Hello world!'` message in simple `HTML`.

But what would be more interesting to get is 'how it works with embedded database' in android,

OR better say, as an example what I mean:

**How to handle JS' "onClick" to get some data stored to db?**

**UPDATE:**

Yeah.. there are a lot of PRODUCTS. But what if I need just a **storage support** (need to put and read data from db). **no need** anything sophisticated like **camera support**. What I really want to avoid is:

1. waiting for Emulator updated
2. write simple and easy components and layout in HTML to get instant result (it seems more natural for me, even though I'm Java Dev.. but it's lame to wait for result building and waiting when working with UI)

**I'm looking for someone's existing experience to avoid addition complexity and time gaps between builds/tries while working with UI.**

Comment: You've just described Cordova, Titanium, Icenium, and lots of other products.

Comment: http://propertycross.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to convert HTML, CSS, and JS code into a native phone app for android or iOS. Very useful as it puts a web wrapper around the web code to run it natively on your phone. This should solve storage issues as well, lots of documentation around for phonegap, be sure to check it out!

Comment: as I understand now it is 'Apache Cordova'. "Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap"...

Comment: @ses Yes that is the underlying technology, Phonegap builds on that a bit with their own features.

Comment: can I work with Phonegap without need to launch Andorid Emulator, like with simple web page + some server? Will investigate it..

Comment: @ses I believe you would need to test the Android app that gets created from Phonegap in the Android Emulator, but for the most part it should convert it to look the same as the HTML/CSS/JS version.

Comment: It seems yes: http://emulate.phonegap.com/ (Ripple Emulation Environment by the BlackBerry HTML Team.)

Answer (score 0):

I just released http://www.protocoder.org under MIT license, give it a try! Its meant to basically do what you mention in the first point (prototype fast), and on the second avoid to learn the Android API to deeply.

Its still a young project but I hope it will grow really fast :)